# casperjs: change test `classname` in output XUnit XML file

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs

I'm using casperjs to run automated interface tests and I generate XUnit-alike XML output file in the end. I wonder if there is any way to override or manually set the test classname? For example, in my output file I've got:

```
<testcase name="Found an element matching: .headerProfile" classname="test/casperjs/casper-test" time="0.002"></testcase>
<testcase name="Found an element matching: .headerCalendarTab" classname="test/casperjs/casper-test" time="0.003"></testcase>
<testcase name="Found an element matching: .headerMetricTab" classname="test/casperjs/casper-test" time="0.002"></testcase>
```

I would like to have:

```
<testcase name="Found an element matching: .headerProfile" classname="xxx" time="0.002"></testcase>
<testcase name="Found an element matching: .headerCalendarTab" classname="xxx" time="0.003"></testcase>
<testcase name="Found an element matching: .headerMetricTab" classname="xxx" time="0.002"></testcase>
```

I've searched the documentation, but found nothing at all...

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `currentTestFile` property of the `casper.test` object. You can do this for the complete file or even for single test blocks.

**For complete test file you can add the following line at the beginning:**

```
casper.test.currentTestFile = "newFileName.js";
```

This will result in

```
<testsuite name="test1" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="0.063" timestamp="2014-07-01T15:37:26.546Z" package="newFileName">
    <testcase name="was true" classname="newFileName" time="0.063"></testcase>
    <system-out></system-out>
</testsuite>
```

This way the testsuite `package` and the testcase `classname` will be `newFileName`.

**If you want to only change the testcases then you need to overwrite the filename this way:**

```
casper.test.begin("test2", function suite(test){
    var oldfile = test.currentTestFile;
    test.currentTestFile = "newFile.js";
    casper.start().then(function(){
        test.assert(true, "was also true");
    }).run(function(){
        test.currentTestFile = oldfile;
        test.done();
    });
});
```

You need to keep in mind to change it back, if you don't want this new file name to be set for the following test suites and test cases.

See this [gist for a complete example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58248519671d54a37ce2).

*Note: This is an **internal** property that is not in the documentation. In the future it might change the behavior or removed alltogether.*

Answer (score 0):

If that is the exact result you want, change your file name to xxx.js, and your result will be classnname='xxx'.

Comment: Thanks, but... that's not what I was expecting ;)